# Salesforce integration(Enterprise API) in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I have done Salesforce integration in .Net but unable to do in windows phone 8. Actually, in .Net we download enterprise API and add it using Add Web Service reference and we get intellisence. Here I there is no option for this. I tried Add Service reference but it did not work. I also tried PCL but still stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also stuck in this problem but I done this through web2Lead. I mean you can integarte this through post data. This is the easy way to do your task done.